# making the user pick between two input files

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is the program I use to ask the user to pick between two files to open:

```
int filenumber; 

cout << "Select the input file :" << endl;
cout << "1. Lab5In-1.txt" << endl;
cout << "2. Lab5In-2.txt" << endl; 

cout << ('\n'); 
cout << ('\n');

cout << "Enter the number of the input files : ";
cin >> fileNumber;

if (fileNumber == 1 )
{
    cout << "The input file Lab5In-1.txt is successfully opend." << endl;
    cout << "The output file Lab5Out-1.txt is sucessfully opened." << endl;
    fin.open("Lab5In-1.txt");
    fout.open("Lab5Out-1.txt");


}
else if (fileNumber == 2)
{
    cout << "The input file Lab5In-2.txt is successfully opend." << endl;
    cout << "The output file Lab5Out-2.txt is sucessfully opened." << endl;
    fin.open("Lab5In-2.txt");
    fout.open("Lab5Out-2.txt");
}
```

This was my objective I am trying to achieve:

```
// Output file options on the screen
// Input the file number from the keyboard
// Determine the input & output files to open & output the file names and opening message to 
//  the screen based on the file number
// Set the formatting for the output file
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Again I say you should not lie to the user. Actually check if the file is successfully open. Instead of unconditionally telling them that it is. In the last question I showed you how to do that. This may actually be related to whatever problem you have.

Comment: Don't ask the User to enter the number (quantity) of input files when you want them to choose from a menu.  Maybe phrase as "Enter selection:".  If I answer 2 to your prompt, I want 2 files opened; not the 2nd selection.

Comment: I think that you advertise `successfully opened` a bit premature :)

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify to this (using table or array lookup):

```
int selection;
// I like block writing to the console.
// Your technique may vary.
static const char menu_text[] = 
"\n"
"Select the input file:\n"
"1. Lab5In-1.txt\n"
"2. Lab5In-2.txt\n"
"Enter selection: ";
std::cout.write(menu_text, sizeof(menu_text));
std::cin >> selection;

static const std::string filenames[] = 
{
    "Invalid filename",
    "Lab5In-1.txt",
    "Lab5In-2.txt",
};
if ((selection < 1) || (selection > 2))
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid selection, aborting.\n";
    return 1;
}
std::string filename = filenames[selection];
std::ifstream data_file(filename.c_str());
```

You can do similar lookup to determine the name of the output file.

**Edit 1: the output filename**

```
static const std::sting output_filenames[] =
{
    "Invalid output filename",
    "Lab5Out-1.txt",
    "Lab5Out-2.txt"
};

const std::string output_filename = output_filenames[selection];
std::ofstream output_file(output_filename.c_str());
```

The above code creates a table of output filenames.  The `selection` variable is used as an index into the array to choose the appropriate filename.

The simplification is that the code to create the filenames and to create the file stream variables is the same regardless of the input selection.

**Edit 2: verification of open**
The verification of whether the file opened or not doesn't depend on the file section:

```
if (!data_file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "File " << filename << " is not opened.\n";
    return 2;
}
if (!output_file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "File " << output_filename << " is not open.\n";
    return 3;
}
```

One of the benefits of simplification is that there is less code to type (thus reducing the chances of typos).  Also, there is less code to compile (speeds up the build process) and less code to review.

Another simplification is to have the User enter the input and output filenames, thus eliminating all the table lookup and filename assignments.